# How to pass authentication and commit in Sourcetree?

Tags: unity-game-engine, atlassian-sourcetree

I cloned a repository from innersource using Git. Now I want to proceed working with the repository using Sourcetree. But when I'm trying to push changes I see the authentification helper popup, and I'm not sure what are these options. If I cancel it, authentification failed.

How can I use or avoid this popup and see some form where I can enter login/password for authentification?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In general: Don't use SourceTree built-in Git! ... they are always like 2 years behind.

Rather directly install [Git](https://git-scm.com) and [Git LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com).

During the `Git` instalation choose the `Credential Manager Core`.

Then when the instalation is done configure Sourcetree to rather use the system Git.

Comment: yes, we had so many strange problems with sourcetree, while standard consoled git worked smooth. Can you please add some details, if possible with screenshots bout how to configure sourcetree to use Git? And Do I need to save my credentials somewhere in global variables (if yes then how), or it will happen automatically?

Comment: @Rumata if you chose the `Credential Manager Core` then it will happen automatically. You can additional store the credentials also directly in SourceTree under Tools -> Options -> Authentication. And there under Tools->Options->Git at the bottom you can switch between the bundled and the system git .. not Back to a PC till Monday so you would need to wait for screenshots ;)